# AWS api gateway upstream authentications

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, kong

I have a question about aws api gateway and it's possibility about upstream authentication.
We come from a monolithic approach and we try to slice into multiple services. We introduced SSO a few weeks ago.

There are some legacy services in place with basic auth credentials or api keys used for machine to machine communication.
Now we want to introduce an api gateway to have a single entrypoint for our clients.

The gateway needs to pass multipart/form-data in form of files and simple json requests as well. The plan is to validate the users in the API Gateway and passthrough the requests to the upstream services.

The services as mentioned above have unfortunately different ways of authentication.

I tried to use AWS API Gateway HTTP API to authenticate against ab backend API secured with basic auth credentials.

The HTTP Api has the advantage that you already have a jwt authroizer in place and you don't need to build your own lambda function for that. Unfortunately you can't set the Authorization header in the HTTP API but you can do in the REST API. I'm also not sure if the REST API will handle multipart/form-data passing through to the destination service.

I already know, that the file limit is 10MB for this requests.

Alternatives like kong, krakend, tyk or others are also welcome when the provide this capabilities as easy as possible.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: will you consider commercial tools or only open-source tools?

Comment: Both are welcome, aws apigateway is commercial isn't it?

Comment: Datawiza provides a solution to validate access token. It works with AWS Rest API gateway so that you don't have to write Lambda. Checkout https://docs.datawiza.com/best-practice/aws-api.html

Comment: ` different ways of authentication.` can you give more details ?
Writing a kong plugin can be the simplest thing to do and this is quite easy

Comment: Hey Ôrel thanks for your answer. I think there are already plugins for kong. Are you using kong already and can you recommend it?